# How to pass value to JS function and, then, to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to show the result of PHP script on div tag without page refresh.
I have a list of .c files (the users can compile them on server)...

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose file </option>';

                    $dirPath = dir('directoryExample');
                    while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
                        {
                            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
                            echo "<option value=\"" . trim($file) . "\">" . $file . "\n";
                        }
                    $dirPath->close();
                    echo '</select>
```

...and two div and button like this:

```
<div id="2" style="display:none;">  </div>
<div id="1" style="display:visible;"> Compile...</div>
<button type="button" onclick="codiad.ccomp.compile(this.value);">Compile</button>
```

First question: How can I pass selected file to JQuery function? this.value works fine?

This is the Jquery function:

```
compile: function(value) {

            if(($('#1').css('display')!='none')){
                    $('#2').load(this.path+'\compile.php').show().siblings('div').hide();
            }else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
                    $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
                }

    }
```

The code works fine but this is second question: how can I pass now the value to php page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a data argument to `.load()`.

```
$('#2').load(this.path+'/compile.php', { file: $("#selectID").val() })
    .show().siblings('div').hide();
```

In the PHP script, use `$_GET['file']` to get the selected filename.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in your first question `this.value` will work fine as `this` refers to the button, not the `select` element.

Instead you would need something like:

```
$('#your_select_element').val();
```

And you can remove the inline javascript and use something like:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // do something with `$('#your_select_element').val();`
  ...
}
```

Assuming there is one button, you might need to add a class or ID to address it specifically.

And as mentioned in the other answer, you can add a data parameter to your `.load()` function.